# CSS submenu ie7 trouble

Tags: css, list, internet-explorer-7, menu, drop-down-menu

I have problem with a css menu. It is correct on firefox,chrome,opera,safari and ie8. But not on ie7. You can find the menu [here](http://valogiannis.com/advocasys/test.html). You can see that every li in the submenu is not shown correctly, it breaks below it. How can I fix it? (I hate ie...).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok..when it's morning you find solutions very fast..Yesterday, for an hour I didn't think to set height on the li and now it was my first thought. Now, if I set  `ul li ul li{height:20px;}` works great!

Thanks to anyone who checked my question & tried to find a solution.